# Which one is correct? "Detail screen" or "Details screen"

Tags: word-usage

Basically I am developing a section for a mobile application where the user can see a list of news and he can click an item in the list to display a more detailed view of that particular item.

Which would be the correct naming for the screen? `Detail Screen` or `Details Screen`?

Comment: Detail is better because it's pronounceable. Also, vitamin shop, not vitamins. Car dealer, not cars.

Comment: The details' screen, if more than one.

Comment: A list of news items, not a list of news. Click **on** an item.

Comment: @YosefBaskin That doesn't seem that important considering it's something users read. And if it's referred to in speech, the pronunciation would be too similar anyway. Since it's about the details of a specific article, I'd opt for Details Screen.

Comment: @Lambie Actually, Bloomberg several years ago shifted their own standards from "click **on** OK" to "click OK."

Comment: Every news story starts with Who...Why, then the details. That's the Full Story, not the Screen with the Details of the News Story.

Comment: "Click OK" is fine. Click an item is **not**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the list displays (not much more than) news item titles, I'd go for 'Details screen', since it displays the details of a news item.

Or, better yet, replace 'screen' with 'window', since the list and the details will be displayed on the same screen (right?).  You can also just use 'Details', 'Item details', or something else to that effect.